# Is it dangerous to name my function ccccvKygDv?

Tags: solidity, security, solc, keccak

For those keeping track at home, the function hash of a function named `ccccvKygDv()` is `0xffffffff`, the same as a null address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract NullFunction {
  function ccccvKygDv() public pure { }
}

contract NormalFunction {
  function NothingWrongHere() public pure { }
}
```

When I look at the opcodes of the two functions listed above, I get:

### NothingWrongHere()

```
47 PUSH4 0xffffffff
52 AND
53 DUP1
54 PUSH4 0xb1f6260f
```

### ccccvKygDv()

```
47 PUSH4 0xffffffff
52 AND
53 DUP1
54 PUSH4 0xffffffff
```

It looks like the data being pushed to the stack will overwrite some of the data needed for the function itself.

Is this a silly question? Absolutely, but I'm asking it so that I can understand how contracts work on the opcode level a bit better.

Comment: "the same as a null address" What do you mean by "a null address"? Are you sure `0xffffffff` isn't just a bit mask? I'd need to see more of the assembly, but that would be my first guess.

Comment: @smarx sorry, it's not a null address (I think), but the largest value a uint of this size can hold. I'm trying to understand if the function hash having this signature will/will not cause any problems and why. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/thoppe/e3935efd55c3a83967d937587097ed38) with the full opcodes.

Comment: I believe my guess was correct. It's just a bit mask used to extract the first four bytes of the call data. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is just a bit mask.

The code loads the call data, shifts it to the right, and then does a bitwise AND with `0xFFFFFFFF` to get the (now) bottom four bytes (the function selector).

Then it compares the four bytes extracted with the known function selector. It doesn't matter that the function signature you're looking for happens to be `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense why it wouldn't cause a problem. What's the point of the bitwise AND though to get the function signature -- isn't it already been pushed onto the stack from `CALLDATALOAD`?

Comment: CALLDATALOAD has more than just four bytes in it. The AND extracts the first 4 bytes. E.g. `0x1234567890abcdef9876 & 0xFFFFFFFF == 0x12345678`.

Comment: A minor correction: bitwise AND with 0xFFFFFFFF will extract the last 4 bytes of a word not first. The first word of input data is divided by `0x0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` before the AND operation to shift the first 4 bytes to the right.